# NoneType seems to be evaluated as True

Tags: python, django, nonetype

I am having this error:

```
  File "/boo/foot/routing/models.py", line 133, in indexing
  contact = self.contact.get_full_name() if self.contact else '',
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_full_name'
```

my code is:

```
class Visit(models.Model):
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True )


    def indexing(self):
        obj = VisitIndex(
            meta = { 'id' : self.id },
            contact = self.contact.get_full_name() if self.contact  else '',
        )
        print(obj)
        obj.save()
```

and the indexing method is attached to the `post_save` signal:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender = Visit)
def index_post(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.indexing()
```

I am testing if `self.contact` is not falsy in order to get `get_full_name()`... yet, it seems even with NoneType it gets to that part. Where could the problem be?

Comment: Anything **OTHER THAN** `None`; `False`; empty containers (strings, dicts, lists); numeric zeros; and user defined False is True in Python. `type(None)` is not empty and not any of the define False things -- therefore `True`.  See [Boolean Operations in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations)

Comment: How about just outputting `self.contact`? The first time you access the object, it's an `ForeignKey` representation - and the result might be different. @dawg - If it were a type object, the error message would be ".. type object 'NoneType' ...".

Comment: @MatsLindh I will try to get he output of self.contact

Answer (score 1):

You already know this, but with your code, that error can only occur if `self.contact` is `None`. But the truthiness test will fail if `self.contact` is `None`, so that section of code can’t be reached. You are right about both of these things. The conclusion must be that something is not as it appears with your code. If you try to put together a minimum, verifiable example (a short section of code that others can run to reproduce the problem), then you will probably find the error. That is similar to a structured debugging process (keep narrowing the problem until you find the source), and I often find I discover my errors as I try to write a good question about them.

Alternatively, as a first debugging step, it would be helpful to take a closer look at `self.contact` Is it `None` or not? You can also make your test a little more precise (although it shouldn't be necessary):

```
def indexing(self):
    print(self.contact) # is it really None?
    if hasattr(self.contact, 'get_full_name'):
        contact = self.contact.get_full_name()
    else:
        contact = ''
    obj = VisitIndex(
        meta={ 'id' : self.id },
        contact=contact,
    )
    print(obj)
    obj.save()
```

This is arguably more 'pythonic' and slightly faster, but I like it less:

```
try:
    get_full_name = self.contact.get_full_name
except AttributeError:
    contact = ''
else:
    contact = get_full_name()
```